# How to read Firebase data using Uid ref?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a `Firebase database` which I can read from and write to from my Android App. However, I am having problems with one aspect of the read.

Users can set up an account in the App (`Firebase` email and password) and are taken to a data input screen and save that information to `Firebase` using this structure:

```
myAndroidApp
    users
      21XKq2RXQYZ36l363msI26XOKdn2
          description: 
          emailAddress: 
          name: 
          ownerName: 
          ..... etc.
```

I have a `PropertyData` Java Class.

The code for saving the data is:

```
PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerName, headline, description....... etc.);
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
databasePropertyData.child(uid).setValue(propertyData);

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        String propNameTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("name").getValue();
        String ownerNameTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("ownerName").getValue();
```

So that all seems to work fine and I can log in to different test users and write to the `Firebase database`.

But what I want is for any existing information in the database to be downloaded and populate the data entry form when the user next signs in. The code I have written does this, but when I sign out of the test account and sign into a different one the data entry form is populated by the previous account!! I thought I was using the `Uid` correctly but obviously not!

When signed into an account if I change the info in the data entry form it does save it to the correct node. So the problem is with the downloading of existing data on startup.

This is the code for downloading existing data to the data entry form:

```
databasePropertyData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

//FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        String propNameTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("name").getValue();
        String ownerNameTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("ownerName").getValue();
        String headlineTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("headline").getValue();
        String descriptionTxt = (String) childSnapShot.child("description").getValue(); 
         ....... etc.
```

I have tried different variations on the listener without success. Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You should not use `child("users" + uid)`. You should use `.child("users").child(uid)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but I also tried that but then no data is downloaded :-(

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all use `...child("users/" + uid)...` instead of `...child("users" + uid)...`. Because you will get the child *`"users21XKq2RXQYZ36l363msI26XOKdn2"`*.

**Second:**
`for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` in your listener already gets child one by one in *`"users/21XKq2RXQYZ36l363msI26XOKdn2"`*. So right now you are trying to get the value of *`"users/21XKq2RXQYZ36l363msI26XOKdn2/name/name"`*, *`"users/21XKq2RXQYZ36l363msI26XOKdn2/description/name"`* and others. I offer you than do it without for cycle.
Like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String propNameTxt = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
    String ownerNameTxt = (String) dataSnapshot.child("ownerName").getValue();
    String headlineTxt = (String) dataSnapshot.child("headline").getValue();
    String descriptionTxt = (String) dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue();
}
```

Also you can create data class with setters and getters for these parameters (*name, ownerName, headline, description*) and use it to get all data.
Like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    MyData data = (MyData) dataSnapshot.getValue(MyData.class);
}
```

Then you can get your field value using getter: `data.getName()`. I am offering setters and getters because you can insert there some validation.
*If you are using data class for Firebase make sure it has an empty constructor.*
More about it in my other answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868970/5272951

Comment: I updated my question to show some additional code. I have setters and getters set up already as you suggested.

Comment: now you should use `if()` method in `for()` cycle to know it data is from *uid* you want.

Comment: What is your main problem? You can't fill up your `String` variables? @PhilipS

Comment: And how to use setters and getters I wrote yesterday there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868970/5272951

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `child("users" + uid)`. To solve this, you have two options:

```
.child("users").child(uid)
```

or

```
child("users/" + uid)
```

Remember, every node in a Firebase database has it's url.

In order to get the from a single authenticated user, you don't need use `getChildren()` method. You also don't need to use `addValueEventListener`, you only need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Please see the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String propNameTxt = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String ownerNameTxt = dataSnapshot.child("ownerName").getValue(String.class);
        String headlineTxt = dataSnapshot.child("headline").getValue(String.class);
        String descriptionTxt = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the database accurate address till where you want to get all the elements on `databaseReference` as you want. Then get the specific element you want to be store by its unique key Ex :-  `dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();` i hope it will help you else reply what you have confusion about firebase connectivity.

```
private String CurrentUserID;    
private DatabaseReference databaseReference

//Outside of Oncreate for user Detection
@Override
protected void onStart(){
     super.onStart();
     mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mauthListener);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mauthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    CurrentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();  
                }
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("myAndroidApp").child("users").child(CurrentUserID);
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String propNameTxt = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String ownerNameTxt = dataSnapshot.child("ownerName").getValue().toString();
                            String headlineTxt = dataSnapshot.child("headline").getValue().toString();
                            String descriptionTxt = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                            }
                }

}
```

Comment: This may be useful for others having the same problem: I understood the logic of the structure of the data and seemed to be pointing at the correct data for each user, and yet the App seemed to load in the wrong data. Then after getting it to work perfectly the App again started to load the wrong data.

After a lot of experimentation I came to realise that locally stored data was being loaded from the emulator or an attached device. If I removed the App and associated data it worked fine. So it was not a coding problem in terms of accessing the data from the server.